# Active record joins in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, join

Trying to return all comments associated with articles written by a particular user.
The following code gives me the error:

```
undefined method `joins' for #<User:0x000001042c8bc0>
```

under Rails 3.1

```
class User
  has_many :articles

  def comments
    self.joins(:articles => :comments)
  end

end
```

Comment: How did you call it? `User.find(params[:id]).comments`?

Comment: ok, you can't do it. Becaues JOIN is a query method, while current_user is an User instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want a `has_many :through` here.

```
class User
  has_many :articles
  has_many :comments, :through => :articles
end
```

Comment: Thanks Dogbert, my question was contrived to make it as simple as possible, the actual problem has many nested joins, so i need a way to make my above example work.

Comment: your above example will never work. @Dogbert solution is the simplest and right one

Comment: "Also, your solution have got right the same join nesting" ??

Comment: "the actual problem has many nested joins", but your solution has many nested joins as well

Comment: @pingu, what exactly are you trying to do with multiple joins? Are you sure you didn't mean to do an `.includes`?